# (ANDROID) Which is the best way? (performance) to create a product catalog application with a WS,

Tags: java, android

I want to create an application that through a WS can show a stock of products, I want to know what is the best way in terms of loading the images, I would also like to ask how to load only 10 items and when doing scroll to load 10 more. Thanks

[image]

Comment: **Welcome to stackoverflow** Have a look **[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**

Comment: You can read about [Android Paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/), although make sure your API also support paging.